# React open full picture onClick

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a few pictures in my react project which I get from my JSON file,I need it to open in full screen when I click on the picture, but the pictures open all at once and not in full screen, perhaps my choice of solution is not the right one.Im new at react so any help or suggestions would help me.  have this code:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardActionArea from "@material-ui/core/CardActionArea";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import CardMedia from "@material-ui/core/CardMedia";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import "../App.scss";

export default class Portfolio extends React.Component {
  state = {
    persons: [],
  };
  handleShowDialog = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen });
    console.log("cliked");
  };
  //   onClick={() => imageClick()}
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3000/persons.json").then((res) => {
      const persons = res.data;
      this.setState({ persons });
    });
  }
  render() {
    // const imageClick = () => {

    //   }
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row justify-content-center">
          {this.state.persons.map((person) => (
            <Card key={person.id} className="col-3 axios-items">
              <CardActionArea>
                <CardMedia
                  component="img"
                  alt={person.alt}
                  height="140"
                  image={person.src}
                  title={person.title}
                  onClick={this.handleShowDialog}
                />
                {this.state.isOpen && (
                  <dialog
                    className="dialog"
                    style={{ position: "absolute" }}
                    open
                    onClick={this.handleShowDialog}
                  >
                    <img
                      className="image"
                      src={person.src}
                      onClick={this.handleShowDialog}
                      alt="no image"
                    />
                  </dialog>
                )}
                <CardContent>
                  <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                    {person.title}
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography
                    variant="body2"
                    color="textSecondary"
                    component="p"
                  >
                    {person.desc}
                  </Typography>
                </CardContent>
              </CardActionArea>
            </Card>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use another state too..

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardActionArea from "@material-ui/core/CardActionArea";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import CardMedia from "@material-ui/core/CardMedia";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import "../App.scss";

export default class Portfolio extends React.Component {
  state = {
    persons: [],
  };
  handleShowDialog = (id) => {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, selected: id, isOpen: true });
    console.log("cliked");
  };
  handleHideDialog = () => {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, isOpen: false });
    console.log("closed");
  };
  //   onClick={() => imageClick()}
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3000/persons.json").then((res) => {
      const persons = res.data;
      this.setState({ persons });
    });
  }
  render() {
    // const imageClick = () => {

    //   }
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row justify-content-center">
          {this.state.persons.map((person) => (
            <Card key={person.id} className="col-3 axios-items">
              <CardActionArea>
                <CardMedia
                  component="img"
                  alt={person.alt}
                  height="140"
                  image={person.src}
                  title={person.title}
                  onClick={()=>{this.handleShowDialog(person.id)}}
                />
                {(this.state.isOpen&&this.state.selected === person.id) && (
                  <dialog
                    className="dialog"
                    style={{ position: "absolute" }}
                    open
                    onClick={this.handleHideDialog}
                  >
                    <img
                      className="image"
                      src={person.src}
                      onClick={this.handleShowDialog}
                      alt="no image"
                    />
                  </dialog>
                )}
                <CardContent>
                  <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                    {person.title}
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography
                    variant="body2"
                    color="textSecondary"
                    component="p"
                  >
                    {person.desc}
                  </Typography>
                </CardContent>
              </CardActionArea>
            </Card>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!